# Dimensions in CNN model don't match input (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm building a CNN according to a [tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2023/04/deep-learning-for-image-segmentation-with-tensorflow/) and having trouble replicating it with 2 classes instead of their 59.

What I changed was for my masks I tried to make them binary:

```
for path in tqdm(msk_paths):
    file = tf.io.read_file(path)
    mask = tf.image.decode_png(file,channels=1,dtype=tf.uint8)
    mask = tf.round(mask/255)
    masks.append(mask)
```

Data shapes and types:

```
X_train.element_spec, y_train.element_spec, X_val.element_spec, y_val.element_spec


(TensorSpec(shape=(128, 128, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(128, 128, 1), dtype=tf.uint8, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(128, 128, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(128, 128, 1), dtype=tf.uint8, name=None))
```

The model:

```
base = keras.applications.DenseNet121(input_shape=[128,128,3], 
                                      include_top=False, 
                                      weights='imagenet')

#final ReLU activation layer for each feature map size, i.e. 4, 8, 16, 32, and 64, required for skip-connections
skip_names = ['conv1/relu', # size 64*64
             'pool2_relu',  # size 32*32
             'pool3_relu',  # size 16*16
             'pool4_relu',  # size 8*8
             'relu'        # size 4*4
             ]

#output of these layers
skip_outputs = [base.get_layer(name).output for name in skip_names]
#Building the downstack with the above layers. We use the pre-trained model as such, without any fine-tuning.
downstack = keras.Model(inputs=base.input,
                       outputs=skip_outputs)
# freeze the downstack layers
downstack.trainable = False

!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git --quiet
from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix

# Four upstack layers for upsampling sizes 
# 4->8, 8->16, 16->32, 32->64 
upstack = [pix2pix.upsample(512,3),
          pix2pix.upsample(256,3),
          pix2pix.upsample(128,3),
          pix2pix.upsample(64,3)]

# define the input layer
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[128,128,3])

# downsample 
down = downstack(inputs)
out = down[-1]

# prepare skip-connections
skips = reversed(down[:-1])
# choose the last layer at first 4 --> 8

# upsample with skip-connections
for up, skip in zip(upstack,skips):
    out = up(out)
    out = keras.layers.Concatenate()([out,skip])
    
# define the final transpose conv layer
# image 128 by 128 with 2 classes
out = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3,
                                  strides=2,
                                  padding='same',
                                  )(out)

# complete unet model
unet = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)


def Compile_Model():
    unet.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
            metrics=['accuracy']) 
Compile_Model()
```

Model summary:

```
Model: "model_10"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_11 (InputLayer)          [(None, 128, 128, 3  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 model_9 (Functional)           [(None, 64, 64, 64)  7037504     ['input_11[0][0]']               
                                , (None, 32, 32, 25                                               
                                6),                                                               
                                 (None, 16, 16, 512                                               
                                ),                                                                
                                 (None, 8, 8, 1024)                                               
                                , (None, 4, 4, 1024                                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 sequential_16 (Sequential)     (None, 8, 8, 512)    4720640     ['model_9[0][4]']                
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_16 (Concatenate)   (None, 8, 8, 1536)   0           ['sequential_16[0][0]',          
                                                                  'model_9[0][3]']                
                                                                                                  
 sequential_17 (Sequential)     (None, 16, 16, 256)  3539968     ['concatenate_16[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_17 (Concatenate)   (None, 16, 16, 768)  0           ['sequential_17[0][0]',          
                                                                  'model_9[0][2]']                
                                                                                                  
 sequential_18 (Sequential)     (None, 32, 32, 128)  885248      ['concatenate_17[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_18 (Concatenate)   (None, 32, 32, 384)  0           ['sequential_18[0][0]',          
                                                                  'model_9[0][1]']                
                                                                                                  
 sequential_19 (Sequential)     (None, 64, 64, 64)   221440      ['concatenate_18[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_19 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           ['sequential_19[0][0]',          
                                                                  'model_9[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_transpose_24 (Conv2DTra  (None, 128, 128, 1)  1153       ['concatenate_19[0][0]']         
 nspose)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16,405,953
Trainable params: 9,366,529
Non-trainable params: 7,039,424
```

But I get the following error when I train it:

```
hist_1 = unet.fit(train,
               validation_data=val,
               steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
               validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS,
               epochs=20,
               verbose=2)
```

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_10" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), found shape=(128, 128, 3)
```

I had multiple other dimension errors before, from the mask channels not matching the output shape, maybe that I'm not using BinaryCrossentropy or missing a softmax layer?

Comment: whatever that `train` variable is, is outputting a single image at a time instead of a batch

Comment: ah tysm I realize I forgot to put 
val = val.batch(BATCH) 
after 
train = train.cache().shuffle(BUFFER).batch(BATCH).repeat()
train = train.prefetch(buffer_size=AT)

Comment: Well, you're are welcome, good luck with your project